# how to loop through data in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my database schema :

[image]

This is the component template :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div v-for="revenue in revenues" :key="revenue._id">
      {{revenue.income}}
    </div>
    {{revenues}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
import axios from "axios"

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      revenues:""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
     axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/revenue`, {})
      .then(response => {
        this.revenues = response.data.revenues;
          })
      .catch(error => {
      });
        // this is the harcoded data which displays chart
        var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'series1',
          data: [31]
        }, {
          name: 'series2',
          data: [11]
        }],
          chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'area'
        },
 
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          categories: ["2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",]
        },
       
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
  },

};
</script>
```

[image]

How can I loop through this data instead of inputing hard coded numbers, this is my json that displays in my broswer.

[image]

How can I input revenue.income in my var option data ?

Comment: Using the documentation https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/area-charts/spline/ and a working example I created with fetching and updating graph data you should be able to create your own chart https://github.com/s-rigaud/huskyfy/blob/main/src/components/playlist_detail/IndieChart.vue

Comment: @SamuelRIGAUD it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to update your then block in the code

```
axios
.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/revenue`, {})
.then(response => {
    this.revenues = response.data.revenues;

    const options = {
        series: [],
        chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'area'
        },

        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            categories: ["2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",]
        },
    }

    this.revenues.forEach(revenue => {
        options.series.push({ name: revenue.time, data: [revenue.income, revenue.expenses] })
    });

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error', error)
});
```

In above code add all the data you want to render in `data` property of options.series array, right now I have added income and expenses.

I suggest you to create seperate method for this logic and call it inside the then block.